# Android background with gradient and tiled image

Tags: android, android-layout

For a linearLayout, I want to have a gradient along with a tiled (repeated) image in the background. I already have a shape xml set as the background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/color1"
        android:startColor="@:color/color2">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

How do I add a tiled bg image?

Comment: Have look at this [link](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html) for a good explanation.

Comment: I know how to do that, what I don't know is how to do both of them together.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Then maybe this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159959/android-circular-gradient-alpha-mask) may help you. I would use the tile image in a bitmap xml as explained in the first link I posted, and then try to add the gradient over it drawing on a canvas like this other SO question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out `LayerLists`.

The following is an XML drawable, called `myBackground.xml`, placed in `res/drawable`.
Set it as the background of the `View` you want to set a gradient and tiled background for.

In the example below, the tiled image will be on top of the gradient, because it is specified later in the `LayerList` - obviously if it's on top, you'll need some transparency on the png image tile (you can set this in an image editing application, like GIMP or Photoshop).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="500"
                android:startColor="#17568A"
                android:endColor="#494C4F" />  

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/tile_classy_fabric"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

"tile_classy_fabric" refers to a file called "tile_classy_fabric.png" in my `res/drawable` folder (250px square, as it's tileable - we don't need it super large).