# Adding gradient to android button with drawable

Tags: android

I want to create a button which includes gradient as well as image as shown:
[image]

The background of the image should be gradient.

Comment: [You can get this answer from here][1] just do the steps and it will help you... :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449311/android-selector-with-background-image-and-gradient

Answer (score 2):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivdpfirst"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sidebutton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_me1" />
```

sidebutton.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#396AA1" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066352/942224

you can create gradient drawable dynamically.. use below class

```
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;

public class SomeDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

public SomeDrawable(int pStartColor, int pCenterColor, int pEndColor, int pStrokeWidth, int pStrokeColor, float cornerRadius) {
    super(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,new int[]{pStartColor,pCenterColor,pEndColor});
    setStroke(pStrokeWidth,pStrokeColor);
    setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
}
```

}

and use this class as below

```
SomeDrawable drawable = new SomeDrawable(Color.parseColor("Start Color Code"),Color.parseColor("Center Color Code"),Color.parseColor("End Color Code"),1,Color.BLACK,00);
yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

and you can set image resource also for that view.

Comment: that is ok but need to place icon as well .